# "What happens when/if..." vs. "what will happen when/if..."

Tags: grammar, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *what happens when/if...* and *what will happen when/if...* For example:

> **What happens** if you lose your job? Do you have a plan?
>
> **What will happen** if you lose your job? Do you have a plan?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["While" and "When" phrases in the future tense.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91042/while-and-when-phrases-in-the-future-tense) In such context, ***if*** refers to "[possible] future" just as much as ***while / when***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tend to use the present tense when we talk about universal situations.

> What happens when you drop a lighted match into a can of petrol?
> What happens if/when you mix oil and water?

We use the future more when talking about a particular situation.

> What will happen if we don't arrive at the airport in good time?
> What will happen if our application for a visa is refused?

In many contexts, including your examples, both are possible.